# I accidentally installed an adware filled Firefox [solved]

Tags: malware, virus, firefox, virus-removal

I installed Firefox using a download site, rather than the correct site.

After running and installing Firefox I noticed my Chrome had an addon called Swift Browser added to it by a third party. After thinking about what I downloaded recently, Firefox came to mind and when I checked the link again I realized my mistake.

Malwarebytes removed 5 things, then using "add or remove" programs I uninstalled Firefox.

I would like to know any other steps I should take or what I should be expecting.

I ran ADWcleaner on advice from a friend. Another thing was removed running HitmanPro 3.7.8.

Hitman Pro removed a few trackers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When compromised you should re-install your machine completely. There is no way of knowing for sure that nothing else has been compromised.

Comment: Take off and nuke the site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Friend recommended to me getting a new hard drive to. Should I go that far or just a new copy of windows?

Comment: @user2860737 Getting a new harddrive seems like a very excessive action. A fresh install of your OS will do.

Comment: I usually recommend getting a new hard drive in these situations. It's not for security (unless you fear being infected by one of the NSA hard drive firmware viruses), but for practicality. Hard drives are cheap nowadays. It's just as easy to reinstall Windows on a new hard disk as on the original, but if you use a new disk, you still have the original one and can (carefully to avoid reinfecting!) copy your old files over.

Comment: @KevinKeane Not saying it is impossible but it would be very hard for a virus to survive a new install if the filesystem is formatted and recreated. The same could be said that it is unknown if the virus infected the BIOs or GPU (which is possible). But realistically I am not going to buy another motherboard or video card.

Comment: @BaconBrad Are there GPU-borne Viruses? I know some viruses can _use_ a GPU, but I never saw anything on the wild able to infect a video card in a way that you should discard it. As far as I know, GPU's don't really hold any form of usable data once you turn them off.

Comment: @T.Sar Technically any hardware that has flashable firmware that can be updated via the machine could be vulnerable. Most high end GPU cards can be updated via software running in the OS. While difficult, it wouldn't be impossible for a programmer to write a virus that could do basically the same thing except with malicious firmware instead of the official firmware. This would then be persistent data even if the card was powered off completely. As far as I know only proof of concepts have been revealed for GPUs but nothing in the wild. The work involved really outweighs the spread on this one.